# Styling an SVG embedded in an object

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<object>
  #document
  <svg></svg>
</object>
```

I want to style the svg's width to be 100% of the parent but since it's technically in a different document I'm having troubles accomplishing that. How would I add width: 100% to the svg element using any means necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent"? Do you mean the `<object>`?

Comment: are you just trying to add an SVG to a page that takes it's width to be 100% of the parent element?

Comment: I'm surprsied `svg` as a child of `object` works [[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)]; also, this is useful: [CSS Tricks on SVGs](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) - see the section on using objects for svgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the object to have your width of `100%`, then edit the SVG to have a width of `100%`. You can see in the xml for the svg, we have a `height` and `width` declaration which are valid for your purposes.

Here, we're setting the object to `100%` width of an `80%` container to illustrate the effect.

```css
.falsy-body {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.falsy-body object {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="falsy-body">
  <object>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="20.267 102.757 588 588" enable-background="new 20.267 102.757 588 588" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.267,104.257h-0.006H314.267z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M593.641,309.856   c7.779,25.038,12.282,51.518,13.015,78.938C606.627,360.895,602.006,334.259,593.641,309.856z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M320.269,689.182   c-1.997,0.04-3.995,0.076-6.002,0.076C316.274,689.258,318.274,689.229,320.269,689.182z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.267,689.258   c-2.007,0-4.005-0.036-6.002-0.076C310.259,689.229,312.259,689.258,314.267,689.258z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M308.266,104.333   c1.995-0.04,3.991-0.076,5.995-0.076C312.256,104.257,310.258,104.286,308.266,104.333z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.268,104.257   C314.268,104.257,314.268,104.257,314.268,104.257c2.007,0,4.005,0.036,6.003,0.076   C318.275,104.286,316.275,104.257,314.268,104.257z"/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="241.3174" y1="737.666" x2="389.318" y2="5.6631" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop offset="0.1" style="stop-color:#E62725"/>
  <stop offset="0.3093" style="stop-color:#ED1C24"/>
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#1C1B1C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M497.885,194.197   c-35.951-52.42-101.821-88.07-177.614-89.864c-1.998-0.041-3.996-0.076-6.004-0.076c-0.002,0-0.004,0-0.006,0   c-2.004,0-4,0.036-5.995,0.076c-127.188,2.562-234.438,86.301-272.078,201.532c18.136-49.932,52.107-90.06,94.523-111.756   c22.219-11.365,46.75-17.683,72.544-17.683c41.792,0,80.278,16.559,110.958,44.369c31.15,28.237,54.245,68.078,64.56,113.999   c3.892,17.322,5.973,35.505,5.973,54.259c0,24.827-3.645,48.653-10.319,70.803c43.404-10.909,81.033-33.316,108.05-63.098   c27.84-30.689,44.418-69.196,44.418-111.013C526.894,252.353,516.317,221.074,497.885,194.197z"/>
 <path fill="#FFF200" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M606.655,388.794   c-0.732-27.42-5.235-53.9-13.015-78.938c-36.443-117.287-144.715-202.931-273.37-205.523   c75.793,1.793,141.663,37.444,177.614,89.864c18.433,26.877,29.009,58.156,29.009,91.548c0,41.817-16.578,80.324-44.418,111.013   c-27.017,29.781-64.646,52.188-108.05,63.098c-19.077,4.795-39.263,7.38-60.159,7.38c-20.939,0-41.165-2.596-60.276-7.41   c11.732,38.949,32.869,72.69,60.221,97.485c30.68,27.81,69.165,44.369,110.956,44.369c31.125,0,60.417-9.186,86.018-25.359   c56.843-35.912,95.473-106.302,95.473-187.267C606.658,388.967,606.655,388.881,606.655,388.794z"/>
 <g>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="309.9668" y1="107.8887" x2="314.2646" y2="107.8887" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0090C7"/>
   <stop offset="0.8326" style="stop-color:#2E3192"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M303.966,689.041    c1.429,0.059,2.862,0.106,4.298,0.141C306.828,689.152,305.398,689.091,303.966,689.041z"/>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="27.7671" y1="364.2666" x2="384.7725" y2="364.2666" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0090C7"/>
   <stop offset="0.8326" style="stop-color:#2E3192"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M249.646,334.825    c20.38-5.543,42.089-8.545,64.622-8.545c22.49,0,44.159,2.99,64.505,8.513c-10.314-45.92-33.409-85.761-64.56-113.999    c-30.68-27.81-69.166-44.369-110.958-44.369c-25.794,0-50.325,6.318-72.544,17.683c-42.417,21.696-76.387,61.824-94.523,111.756    c-8.998,27.543-14.013,56.882-14.375,87.344c-0.014,1.183-0.045,2.361-0.045,3.547c0,158.094,125.431,286.855,282.199,292.285    c-84.513-3.441-156.088-48.998-186.572-112.624c-10.147-21.179-15.754-44.354-15.754-68.649c0-41.816,16.579-80.322,44.418-111.01    C172.146,368.001,208.125,346.119,249.646,334.825z"/>
 </g>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="282.7324" y1="647.4258" x2="404.7324" y2="161.4258" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop offset="0.6047" style="stop-color:#006838"/>
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#538B2E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M606.767,396.756   c0-2.662-0.04-5.315-0.111-7.961c0,0.086,0.003,0.172,0.003,0.259c0,80.965-38.63,151.355-95.473,187.267   c-25.601,16.174-54.893,25.359-86.018,25.359c-41.791,0-80.276-16.56-110.956-44.369c-27.353-24.795-48.489-58.536-60.221-97.485   c-6.669-22.141-10.311-45.956-10.311-70.772c0-18.743,2.079-36.915,5.965-54.228c-41.521,11.294-77.5,33.176-103.587,61.933   c-27.84,30.688-44.418,69.193-44.418,111.01c0,24.296,5.607,47.471,15.754,68.649c31,64.702,104.491,110.721,190.87,112.765   c1.997,0.04,3.995,0.076,6.002,0.076s4.005-0.036,6.002-0.076c1.438-0.034,2.87-0.082,4.301-0.141   C481.337,683.61,606.767,554.849,606.767,396.756z"/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="249.6802" y1="400.2422" x2="390.7451" y2="400.2422" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" fill-opacity="0" d="M378.772,334.793c-20.346-5.523-42.015-8.513-64.505-8.513   c-22.533,0-44.242,3.002-64.622,8.545c-3.887,17.313-5.965,35.485-5.965,54.228c0,24.816,3.641,48.631,10.311,70.772   c19.111,4.814,39.337,7.41,60.276,7.41c20.896,0,41.082-2.585,60.159-7.38c6.675-22.15,10.319-45.977,10.319-70.803   C384.745,370.298,382.664,352.115,378.772,334.793z"/>
</g>
</svg>
  </object>
</div>
```